# Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-java@v3, warchant/setup-sonar-scanner@v7

Tags: node.js

Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-java@v3, warchant/setup-sonar-scanner@v7

I'm trying pipeline with sonar.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 29):

This seems to be a warning message in GitHub Actions.

The default workflow YAML file that GitHub generated for my Python project has a
similar warning message:

> Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please
> update the following actions to use Node.js 20: `actions/checkout@v3`, `actions/setup-python@v3`

Although the reason is explained in [this article](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/), the solution is not so easily captured by readers from such a lengthy article.

A quick answer for those busy engineers, replace following

- `actions/checkout@v3` with `actions/checkout@v4`
- `actions/setup-python@v3` with`actions/setup-python@v4`

Comment: If you want to make sure of the latest version of a GitHub action, e.g., actions/checkout, you may visit [https://github.com/actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout), search "Latest", and see its latest release is v4.1.1.  Then according to the syntax of [Using Versioned Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-versioned-actions), you may reference the major version of a release by "actions/checkout@v4".

Comment: as of Mar 2024 I had to use `actions/setup-python@v5` to get rid of the warning